# Show content depending on current site

Tags: php, javascript

Is it possible to accomplish the same using JavaScript?

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$needle = 'php';

if(strstr($url, $needle)){
    $bool = true;
    }
else{
    $bool = false;
}


if($bool){
?>
    Text
<?php
}else{
?>
    Another text...
<?php
}
?>
```

Basically I need to display different HTML content depending on the current site. Some parts are being included into different sites.

***EDIT:***

Is it OK, to do it this way:

```
<script>
var url = document.URL;
var needle = 'test';
var bool = false;
if(url.indexOf(needle) != -1){
  bool=true;
}
document.write(bla);
</script>


<table border="1">
<script>
if(bool){
  document.write('<tr><td>abc</td><td>def</td></tr>');
}
</script>
  <tr><td>ghi</td><td>jkl</td></tr>
</table>
```

I'm not sure about the JavaScript **within** the table...

Comment: If you have this in PHP, why do you need to do it via JavaScript?

Comment: Why do something client-side when you can do it better server-side?

Comment: Show us the JavaScript code you're having trouble with, and I'm sure someone will be able to help.

Comment: Because my server doesn't support PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. Just use `location.href.indexOf("php") > -1` to see if it's there.